# Lucas formula solved with recursion. Yet formula has not been defined

Tags: ruby, recursion

The code works perfectly. I want to know how. during debugging I can see that " seq " gets its initial value at the first recursion. Here seq[-1] + seq[-2] is correct when you have a starting point. I can see when, but don't understand how. The initial sequence has not been given. That is not the case. It starts correctly with [2, 1].

```
def lucas_sequence(length)
   if length == 0
       return [] 
   elsif length == 1
       return [2]
   elsif length == 2
       return [2, 1]
   else
       seq = lucas_sequence(length -1)
       next_el = seq[-1] + seq[-2]
       seq << next_el
       seq
   end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the entire method? For one, readers can't test code without it.

Comment: That is the entire method. To run this method would go as follows " p lucas_sequence(4) " =>  ruby code.rb and you would get [2, 1, 3, 4] All of the code is there. It is processed with recursion.

Comment: Sorry, my mitake. When I first saw it (on my phone) the first line seemed to be missing

Comment: No problem, thanks for looking. Obviously I am a student solving practice solutions. I am running Ruby 2.7.1. Can you explain how this code is achieving a starting point other than seq[0, 0]?

Comment: @Phillip : You also need to show how you are invoking this function. As to your question _I want to know how. during debugging I can see that " seq " gets its initial value at the first recursion_ : Just output the variable of `length` at the start of the function, and the value of `seq` immediately after the recursive call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I realized some of the solution while posting this query. In an array -1 is the last position and -2 is the second from the last. [0, 0], because it is initialized, seq[-1] + seq[-2], seq == seq[2, 1].

I understand the positions without contest, no problem there.

Why the values though? // The values had not been assigned yet.

Why not [0, 0]? // The following explains how the initial values are produced.

// => I found the answer.

Previously I was not keeping track of the variable (length).

That is why I did not see how this method using recursion gained it's initial values. This is how the method was executed in the 'byebug' debugger. If you are not familiar with byebug it is a simple gem install.

user$gem install byebug

```
require 'byebug'   

def lucas_sequence(length)
   if length == 0
       return [] 
   elsif length == 1
       return [2]
   elsif length == 2
       return [2, 1]
   else
       debugger # AKA this is a breakpoint in byebug          
       seq = lucas_sequence(length -1)
       next_el = seq[-1] + seq[-2]
       seq << next_el
       seq
   end
end

p lucas_sequence(12) # Calling method asking to print to console
               # Asking for a Lucas Sequence with a length of 12
```

These are the results including the initiation of 'byebug' variable value tracking.

```
   user$ruby file.rb
   45:       return [2]
   46:   elsif length == 2
   47:       return [2, 1]
   48:   else
   49:       debugger  
=> 50:       seq = lucas_sequence(length -1) # This is a recursive loop     
   51:       next_el = seq[-1] + seq[-2]
   52:       seq << next_el
   53:       seq
   54:   end
  (byebug) disp length     
  1: length = 12     
  (byebug) disp seq
  2: seq = nil
  (byebug) disp next_el
  3: next_el = nil
  (byebug)_
```

After iterating several times the variable "seq" gains it's first value.

This is how the sequence became initiated.

```
   user$ruby file.rb
   45:       return [2]
   46:   elsif length == 2
   47:       return [2, 1]
   48:   else
   49:       debugger
=> 50:       seq = lucas_sequence(length -1) 
   51:       next_el = seq[-1] + seq[-2]
   52:       seq << next_el
   53:       seq
   54:   end
   (byebug) n      
   1: length = 3
   2: seq = [2, 1] # Now seq has a value other than nil
   3: next_el = nil
   (byebug)_
```

As we can see now the variable length is equal to 3

That makes line 50: seq = lucas_sequence(length -1) equal to (3 - 1).

Which gives us the return value for length == 2. Length of (3 - 1) is indeed equal to the value for length of (2).

That is how this method gains it's initial values to produce a Lucas sequence.
=>  seq = [2, 1]

The sequence for the length of 12 is:

=> [2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 11, 18, 29, 47, 76, 123, 199]

Comment: This is not really an answer, so I suggest you edit your question to include this information. Feel free to simply re-write your question rather that identifying the bits you are adding.